# Adding div in table

Tags: html

I'm looking to add some kind of separator within a table so I can apply a styling to a specific portion of the table. The table it divided into six columns which are two sets of the subject, the input box, and the marker.

When I add  tags, they're thrown to the top when the html is rendered (inspect element on the jsfiddle). Can I add some kind of separator (div, span, or something else) such that each set of three has only one subject, one input box, and one marker.

I need this because when I add a check mark or x to a marker using jQuery, it bleeds over and styles the other marker in the same row the same way. Looking to make them independent.

https://jsfiddle.net/sLy9d67r/

```
    <div class="conjugate-input-container ">
      <table class="table table-striped conjugate-input">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
           <div>
            <td class="subject">je</td>
            <td class="conj-input"><input type="text" id="conj1sg" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" ></td>
            <td class="marker"><i class="fa "></i></td>
           </div>
           <div>
            <td class="subject">nous</td>
            <td class="conj-input"><input type="text" id="conj1pl" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="4" ></td>
            <td class="marker"><i class="fa "></i></td>
           </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <div>
            <td class="subject">tu</td>
            <td class="conj-input"><input type="text" id="conj2sg" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="2" ></td> 
            <td class="marker"><i class="fa "></i></td>
           </div>
           <div>
            <td class="subject">vous </td>
            <td class="conj-input"><input type="text" id="conj2pl" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="5" ></td>     
            <td class="marker"><i class="fa "></i></td>
           </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <div>
            <td class="subject">il</td>
            <td class="conj-input"><input type="text" id="conj3sg" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="3" ></td>     
            <td class="marker"><i class="fa "></i></td>
           </div>
           <div>
            <td class="subject">ils</td>
            <td class="conj-input"><input type="text" id="conj3pl" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="6" ></td>     
            <td class="marker"><i class="fa "></i></td>
           </div>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a table, you can only insert other elements (eg, span div) in the td. Div's are not allowed between two tr(s) or two td(s).

Comment: can I group three columns in each row together some way?

Comment: @SethKillian Yeah of course. The three columns make up a row. So you can apply your desired style to tr that contains the three colums colums.

Comment: The setup I have is six columns make up a row because I'm looking to keep alignment. Can I break up the first and second set of three while maintaining the present alignment?

Comment: Yeah you can play with them as u wish. Use colspan and rowspan. I think this will be helpful https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp